# Composing Images to a row with ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing, command-line, imagemagick

I have about 650 `gif` files with sprites, but I can't display them animated in a `<canvas>`, so I would need to turn them into spritesheets, every animation into a single `png`.

It's obvious why I don't want to do all this by hand with Gimp. I have found a way to extract the frames of the `gif` into individual files:

```
convert image.gif -depth 32 /tmp/frames%02d.png
```

Very simple, but I am stuck with a problem: Now I want to make a single `png` out of them, in one row. How can I compose them correctly?

It'd be great if anyone could help me.

**EDIT**: Found out how to preserve transparency myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret is the `-append` option:

```
convert +append frame*.png sprite.png
```

Works nicely.